# Why does Xdebug 3.1 not report ZipArchive function time?

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug, php-7.3

### Context

In a legacy app I am profiling a script that archives files in a zip. At the moment it takes about 30-35 seconds to add 55MB (~450 files) to a zip archive on a locally-running VM. I was hoping to figure out where I might improve that via profiling. The app runs on PHP 7.3 (it doesn't function on 8.x unfortunately) and Xdebug 3.1.6 is the latest version that supports this; the app includes a version of pclzip for creating archives, which I thought I would profile in comparison to native PHP zip handling to see if there is a substantial difference.

I've written a functional test using Selenium to roughly measure the archive time, and both approaches take roughly the same time, ~30-35 seconds.

### kcachegrind output

Xdebug produces a breakdown of time spent and a call graph as expected for pclzip:

[image: pcl time spent]

[image: pcl call graph]

However Xdebug doesn't show the same time breakdown for native zip handling (ZipArchive):

[image: ZipArchive time]

[image: ZipArchive call graph]

Interestingly, the cachegrind files produced are of substantially-different sizes too:

```bash
$ ls -lh cachegrind.out.??.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 bertieb bertieb  32M Jan  5 12:06 cachegrind.out.23.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 bertieb bertieb 231K Jan  5 12:09 cachegrind.out.26.gz
```

*(`cachegrind.out.23.gz` is the pclzip profile, `cachegrind.out.26.gz` is ZipArchive)*

### Question

What is the reason for this difference? I would expect to see similar time breakdowns and call graphs for both approaches. I am quite new to Xdebug, and searches didn't shed any light on this discrepancy.

---

#### Test code

The zip-creating/updating code for existing pclzip code:

```php
// in a loop
    $archive = new PclZip ($zipfilename);
    $archive->add ($filename, PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_PATH, $removedir);
// loop continues
```

Create/update code for ZipArchive:

```php
// also in loop
    $archive = new ZipArchive();
    $zipres = $archive->open($documentName, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    if ($zipres) {
        $storename = substr($filename, strpos($filename, "upload/"));
        $archive->addFile($filename, $storename); 
        $archive->setCompressionName($storename, ZipArchive::CM_STORE); // contents not very compressible
        // $archive->close(); // ← not performed here as slows down script by ⅙ to ⅓, deferred until after loop instead
    }
// loop continues
// in cleanup
if ($archive) $archive->close();
```

Comment: If there is any further information needed / clarifications needed / any other improvements for this Q that would help I am happy to edit them in

Comment: Is it because ZipArchive is too fast?

Comment: @shingo Unfortunately not- both ZipArchive and pclzip take roughly the same amount of time. Good thought though, I'll edit that in!

Comment: You should provide test code. From the image, it appears that the second method spent most of its time on main function, and the file size also shows that there was an issue with the compression process.

Comment: @shingo test code added. I agree the file size difference shows something odd going on with the zip process, it's odd that it doesn't seem to affect the over archive time to a greater extent

Comment: `$zipres->close`? But it's a bool, and _in cleanup_? Note that ZipArchive writes data when close is called, so youshould call it asap.

Comment: @shingo My mistake, should have been `$archive->close();` in the Q, have updated accordingly. You're right about the timing of writes: I originally had `close()` in the loop as soon as the archive had been added to, but this seemed to have a somewhat detrimental impact on perf so I deferred calling `close()` until cleanup (on retesting, it adds 5-10s to processing time)

Comment: If you can reproduce this with a short script, can you file a bug at https://bugs.xdebug.org ?

Comment: @Derick Sure, I'll write up a MWE and test against latest Xdebug and see if the behaviour persists. Interestingly, changing the process by which the ZIP is created (ground up rewrite of that part of the app) lets the archive be created in a much more reasonable time (~1s); which I wouldn't have necessarily expected from either of the profiles- it feels like either time isn't being fully accounted for, or I am using Xdebug wrong/reading Kcachegrind wrong!

Comment: I don't think I've seen a bug report yet?